# Run convert from VBScript on all files in a folder

Tags: vbscript, command, imagemagick-convert

Im trying to call this external command to convert every file in a directory from VBScript:

```
convert -type bilevel -compress group4 -pointsize 20 -draw "text 10,20 'PropertyValue1 PropertyValue2 PropertyVAlue3 PropertyValue4 PropertyValue5' " input.tif output.tif
```

When im running below script on Windows 10 64-bit nothing happens. I already checked variables. It looks like I'm doing something wrong here, but I have no idea what.

VBScript:

```
strFolder1 = "C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Nowyfolder\PDF TO TIFF imagemagick\tify" 'path to folder with .tif files ready to convert to readable tif

Dim aFileNameSize(0, 0)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder1)
Set colFiles = colFolder.Files

Dim list
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each strFile In colFiles
  aFileNameSize(0,0) = strfile.Name
  list.Add strfile.name
Next

For i = 0 To list.Count
  Do:
    If i = list.Count Then Exit Do

    Dim x
    a = "C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Nowyfolder\PDF TO TIFF imagemagick\tify "
    d = """text 10,20 'PropertyValue1 PropertyValue2 PropertyVAlue3 PropertyValue4 PropertyValue5"
    f = "'"
    g = "" & Chr(34) & ""
    h = "" & d & "" & "" & f & "" & "" & Chr(32) & "" & "" & g & ""
    b = "convert -type bilevel -compress group4 -pointsize 20 -draw " & d & "" & "" & f & "" & "" & Chr(32) & "" & "" & g &  ""
    c = "" & list.Item(i) & ""
    x = "" & a & "" & "" & b & "" & "" & list.Item(i) & "" & Chr(32) & "" & "" & c & ""

    Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
    oShell.Run "cmd cd """ & x & """"
  Loop While False
Next
```

Comment: Why all these empty lines in your code - doesn't render it better readable. The for i should be `For i = 0 to list.Count -1` amd omit the do Loop entirely. You should echo all these single letter vars to be shure they contain what you want. Vars a and strfolder1 have the same content so one var should be sufficient.

Comment: Folder access permissions?

Comment: I have fixed it by doing more echo debugging.

Comment: Add a / after C..... cmd /c <-- cmd run this command. Also your "" between ampersands are useless. In order to specify use of double-quotes, you enter double-double-quotes and encase them in double quotes as a string. & """" & """"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I took a stab at it. Seems you've got a lot of excessive work for nothing. A lot of strings combining empty strings and characters... See below. Test it out making any syntax adjustments and you're all set.

The shell command execution will run as this in the current formatting....

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Nowyfolder\PDF TO TIFF imagemagick\tify\convert.exe -type bilevel -compress Group4 -pointsize 20 -draw "text 10,20 \'PropertyValue1 PropertyValue2 PropertyVAlue3 PropertyValue4 PropertyValue5\'" somefile.tif"
```

Here's the VBS

```
strfldr = "C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Nowyfolder\PDF TO TIFF imagemagick\tify"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strfldr)
Set colFiles = colFolder.Files
'unnecessary array removed

For Each objfile In colFiles 'Properly notate file as Object, not string
    'if instr(1, objFile.Name, ".tif", 1) <> 0 Then ShellRun(ConvertFile(objFile.Name))
    if instr(1, objFile.Name, ".tif", 1) <> 0 Then ShellExec(ConvertFile(objFile.Name))
Next

Function ConvertFile(strFileName)
    Exec = "C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Nowyfolder\PDF TO TIFF imagemagick\tify\convert.exe"
    TypeParam = "-type bilevel"
    CompParam = "-compress Group4"
    PsizeParam = "-pointsize 20"
    DrawParam = "-draw ""text 10,20 \'PropertyValue1 PropertyValue2 PropertyVAlue3 PropertyValue4 PropertyValue5\'"""
    Params = TypeParam & " " & CompParam & " " & PsizeParam & " " & DrawParam & " " & strFileName & " " & strFileName
    ConvertFile = """" & Exec & " " & Params & """"
    'Returns properly formatted Command string
End Function

Function ShellRun(strCommand)
    On Error Resume Next
    if NOT isObject(shell) then Set shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    wscript.echo strcommand
    shell.run "cmd.exe /c " & strCommand, 0, true
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        msgbox "Error Code:" & err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, 0, "Shell Command Error " & err.number & "!"
        err.clear
    End if
    on error goto 0
    Set shell = nothing
    'Executes command shell hidden - returns error code via msgbox.
End Function

Sub ShellExec(strCommand)
    ShellExecReturn = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("cmd /c " & strCommand ).stdout.readall
    wscript.sleep 1000
    wscript.echo ShellExecReturn
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there way to NOT execute every file conversion in the same time? I know there is sleep command but how to properly evaluate process time?

Comment: Use shell exec instead of shell run and it will run sequentially. You can add wscript.sleep 1000 at the end of the for loop for a delay of 1 second/ 1000 milliseconds as for the example.

Comment: Add more time as seconds x 1000 as the wscript.sleep parameter is milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Im posting fixed code :

```
strFolder1 = "C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Nowyfolder\PDF TO TIFF imagemagick\tify" 'path to folder with .tif files ready to convert to readable tif

Dim aFileNameSize(0, 0)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set colFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder1)

Set colFiles = colFolder.Files

dim list
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")


For Each strFile In colFiles

aFileNameSize(0,0) = strfile.name

list.Add strfile.name

Next


For i = 0 to list.Count -1
Do:
 If i = list.Count Then Exit Do


Dim x
a = "C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\Nowyfolder\PDF TO TIFF imagemagick\tify "

d = """text 10,20 'PropertyValue1 PropertyValue2 PropertyVAlue3 PropertyValue4 PropertyValue5"

f = "'"

g = "" & chr(34) & ""


h = "" & d & "" & "" & f & "" & "" & chr(32) & "" & "" & g & ""


n = """" & strFolder1 & """"


b = "convert -type bilevel -compress group4 -pointsize 20 -draw " & d & "" & "" & f & "" & "" & chr(32) & "" & "" & g &""


c = "" & list.item(i) & ""


x = "" & b & "" & "" & chr(32) & "" & "" & list.item(i) & "" & chr(32) & "" & "" & c & ""





Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run "cmd /K CD " & n & " & " & x & "", 0, True




Loop While False
Next
```